# Read Response Until Certain Character

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am building an application that needs to read a string response from a device and convert it into a byte array. Each string I receive finishes with a new line & carriage return "\n\r". I am trying to find a way to read all of the characters until the "\n\r" is given.

So for example if I received a response "1AF32AEF\n\r" I would only want to read "1AF32AEF" and ignore the "\n\r". I tried the `.ReadTo` method but I am not sure if that's what I need. Below is the line of code I am using to try to accomplish this.

```
string result = serialport.ReadTo("\n\r");
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure it's \n\r? Because normally a newline is \r\n

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ReadLine`   instead of `ReadTo`. Because they are CarriageReturn + NewLine chars....

Answer (score 1):

I think that L.B's answer can solve the problem, but another approach is to use 'split' with '\n\r' and then you'll have an array of strings